# yii manage configuration from database

Tags: php, yii

I am working on yii framework. I have **tbl_setting** table and **Setting** model. Which have many keys and values. Admin can change all values from admin panel. Table structure is shown below:

```
 define           Value     
 COMPANY_NAME     Google    
 META_TITLE       .::My Site::.
 ........  
 ........
```

In core php i was defining all key values using define(), in yii how can i use it globally?

I was trying to set in params on main.php file but i can not use Setting model there.

---

I found the answer. I have done using below approach. I am not sure if this is the good practice or not, if anyone know other good way please post.

Created new component: WebSetting.php

```
class WebSetting extends CApplicationComponent
{
    function getValue($key)
    {
        $model = Setting::model()->findByAttributes(array('define'=>$key));
        return $model->value;
    }
}
```

main.php

```
'setting'=>array('class'=>'WebSetting'),
```

And now i can access all values anywhere using:

```
 echo Yii::app()->setting->getValue('META_TITLE'); 
 echo Yii::app()->setting->getValue('COMPANY_ADDRESS');
```

Comment: why do you want to set that in the main configuration file? what are these settings for?

Comment: You should take a look at this http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/187/how-to-write-a-simple-application-component

Comment: @Orlymee It can be any global setting. i.e. admin can set meta title for front side's pages. @ ors I am checking it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new application component

```
    class EConfig extends CApplicationComponent
{
    public $cache = 0;
    public $dependency = null;

    protected $data = array();

    public function init()
    {

        $items=Config::model()->findAll();


        foreach ($items as $item)
        {
            if ($item['param'])
                $this->data[$item['param']] = $item['value'] === '' ?  $item['default'] : $item['value'];
        }
        parent::init();
    }

    public function get($key)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->data))
            return $this->data[$key];
        else
            //throw new CException('Undefined parameter ' . $key);
            return '';
    }

    public function set($key, $value)
    {
        $model = Config::model()->findByAttributes(array('param'=>$key));
        if (!$model)
            throw new CException('Undefined parameter ' . $key);

        $model->value = $value;

        if ($model->save())
            $this->data[$key] = $value;

    }

    public function add($params)
    {
        if (isset($params[0]) && is_array($params[0]))
        {
            foreach ($params as $item)
                $this->createParameter($item);
        }
        elseif ($params)
            $this->createParameter($params);
    }

    public function delete($key)
    {
        if (is_array($key))
        {
            foreach ($key as $item)
                $this->removeParameter($item);
        }
        elseif ($key)
            $this->removeParameter($key);
    }

    protected function getDbConnection()
    {
        if ($this->cache)
            $db = Yii::app()->db->cache($this->cache, $this->dependency);
        else
            $db = Yii::app()->db;

        return $db;
    }

    protected function createParameter($param)
    {
        if (!empty($param['param']))
        {
            $model = Config::model()->findByAttributes(array('param' => $param['param']));
            if ($model === null)
                $model = new Config();

            $model->param = $param['param'];
            $model->label = isset($param['label']) ? $param['label'] : $param['param'];
            $model->value = isset($param['value']) ? $param['value'] : '';
            $model->default = isset($param['default']) ? $param['default'] : '';
            $model->type = isset($param['type']) ? $param['type'] : 'string';

            $model->save();
        }
    }

    protected function removeParameter($key)
    {
        if (!empty($key))
        {
            $model = Config::model()->findByAttributes(array('param'=>$key));
            if ($model)
                $model->delete();
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can use it for Adding param to database (if there is not such param yet)

```
  Yii::app()->config->add(array(
                'param'   => 'PARAMNAME',
                'label'   => 'yourlabel',
                'value'   => 4534,
                'type'    => 'integer',
                'default' => 4534,
            ));
```

Getting param value -

```
Yii::app()->config->get('PARAMNAME');
```

Setting param value (if param exists)

```
Yii::app()->config->set('PARAMNAME',100500);
```

Of course you will need to create table and class and controller for it

```
    CREATE TABLE `Config` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `param` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  `default` text NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `param` (`param`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=290 ;
```

And add some changes to config

```
 components=>array(
 ...
  'config' => array(
          'class' => 'application.extensions.components.EConfig',
         //   'cache'=>3600,
       ),
```

And add config to preload section in config

```
 'preload' => array(..,'config'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using,

```
<?php
class SitesettingWidget extends CWidget {

    public function run() {
        $siteData = SiteSetting::model()->findAll(); 

        $this->render('setting', array(
            'siteData'=>$siteData,   
        ));
    }
}
```

But think CApplicationComponent is better way...